# use preceding in calculation sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to calculate the column E using column B,C,D & previous row of E... I have the sample statement and calculation for reference. Note that prev(E) is the preceding value of E which I need to use in calculation but am unable to.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| TransactionDt | total_allotment(B) | invchange(C) | roomssold_flag(D) | available(E) |       samplestatement            | calculation |   
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|    1/1/16     |         5          |      0       |       null        |       5      |  E=case when D=null then B       |  5          |   
|    1/2/16     |         5          |      0       |        1          |       4      |  E=case when C=0 then prev(E)-D  |  E=(5-1)    |   
|    1/3/16     |         5          |      0       |        0          |       4      |  E=case when C=0 then prev(E)-D  |  E=(4-0)    |   
|    1/4/16     |         6          |      1       |        1          |       5      |  E=case when C=1 then B-D        |  E=(6-1)    |   
|    1/5/16     |         6          |      0       |        0          |       5      |  E=case when C=0 then prev(E)-D  |  E=(5-0)    |   
|    1/6/16     |         7          |      1       |        1          |       6      |  E=case when C=1 then B-D        |  E=(7-1)    |   
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Preceding by what clause? By previous TransactionDt?

Comment: Yes. Sample statement and example might help you.

Comment: At 1/5/16 row, E=(5-2), isn't that should be E=(5-0) because D=0?

Comment: Based on your calculation you need to restart `available` whenever  `invchange` is `1`?

Comment: thanks @SlavaN. corrected it.

Comment: @dnoeth You got it dnoeth. And I'm on Teradata.

Comment: What's your Teradata release? Is `total_allotment` correlated to `invchange`, i.e.the value increases when `invchange=1`?

Comment: Yes that's right. That's a field I created based on total_allotment change. Teradata v15.10

Comment: @dnoeth it's the other way round though.. when total_allotment changes, invchange becomes 1.. otherwise it remains 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use first_value() function with preceding clause to get privious value:

```
set dateformat dmy;
declare @t table (TransactionDt smalldatetime, b int, c int, d int, e int);
insert into @t (TransactionDt, b, c, d, e) values
(cast('01.01.2016' as date), 5, 0, null, 5),
(cast('02.01.2016' as date), 5, 0, 1, 4),
(cast('03.01.2016' as date), 5, 0, 0, 4),
(cast('04.01.2016' as date), 6, 1, 1, 5),
(cast('05.01.2016' as date), 6, 0, 0, 5),
(cast('06.01.2016' as date), 7, 1, 1, 6);

select
  t.*
  ,first_value(t.e) over(order by t.TransactionDt asc rows 1 preceding) [prevE]
  ,case t.c
     when 0 then
       first_value(t.e)
       over(order by t.TransactionDt asc rows 1 preceding)
       - t.d
     when 1 then
       t.b - t.d
   end [calculation]
from
  @t t
order by
  t.TransactionDt
;
```

Tested on MS SQL 2012.

I'm not big fan of Teradata, but this should work:

```
select
  t.e
  ,sum(t.e) 
  over(order by t.TransactionDt asc rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) ePrev
  ,case t.c
     when 0 then
       sum(t.e) 
       over(order by t.TransactionDt asc rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)
       - t.d
     when 1 then
       t.b - t.d
   end calculation
from
  (
    select cast('01.01.2016' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy') TransactionDt, 5 b, 0 c, null d, 5 e from (select 1 x) x
    union all
    select cast('02.01.2016' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy') TransactionDt, 5 b, 0 c, 1 d, 4 e from (select 1 x) x
    union all
    select cast('03.01.2016' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 5, 0, 0, 4 from (select 1 x) x
    union all
    select cast('04.01.2016' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 6, 1, 1, 5 from (select 1 x) x
    union all
    select cast('05.01.2016' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 6, 0, 0, 5 from (select 1 x) x
    union all
    select cast('06.01.2016' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 7, 1, 1, 6 from (select 1 x) x
  ) t
order by
  t.TransactionDt
;
```

Comment: Is there a way in Teradata?

Comment: Add posible solution to Teradata

Answer (score 0):

When you need to restart the calculation whenever `invchange=1` you have to create a group for partitioning using

```
sum(invchange)
over (order by TransactionDt
      rows unbounded preceding) as grp
```

`invchange` seems to be based on a previous row query, so you need to nest it't calculation in a Dervied Table.

Now you it's the `total_allotment` value minus a Cumulative Sum over `roomssold_flag`:

```
select t.*,
   b - sum(coalesce(D,0))
       over (partition by grp
             order by TransactionDt
             rows unbounded preceding)
from
 (
   select TransactionDt,b,c,d,
      sum(c) over (order by TransactionDt rows unbounded preceding) as grp
   from t
 ) as t
```

Btw, using a 0/1 flag to get dynamic partitioning is similar to `RESET WHEN`

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear on that. I created the field invchange. Whenever total_allotment would change (based on a timestamp), I would have a flag 1 for invchange. Note that it's NOT the cumulative sum.

Comment: @Kash: Is it possible that `total_allotment` decreases over time? Otherwise you can still use it for partitioning...

Comment: It might increase or decrease. I'll tell you the problem. Total allotment is not reflecting the rooms sold. Only when someone manually increase or decrease the inventory. So technically I have to use the allotment until there is no change in inventory. When there is change in inventory, I would use the changed(updated) record to calculate the available rooms.